# Tikz nodes inherit minimum width, what else?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, parameters

OK, it may seem stupid, but I often have tikz nodes inside a tikz environment inside a tikz node.

When the outer node has parameter `minimum width` set to non zero, it appears the inner node inherits this setting:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{m/.style={draw, minimum width=2cm}}

\tikz\node[m]{(\tikz\node[fill=yellow]{Hello};]};

\tikz\node[m]{(\tikz\node[fill=blue, minimum width=0]{Hello};]};
\end{document}
```

While I know that color of the outer node is applied to the inner node, this does not fall under the qualification of "inheritance". Other common settings (`fill`, `draw`, `text`, `inner sep`, `outer sep`) don't seem to be inherited either.

Is this documented? Are there other settings behaving the same way? Is it avoidable without force-setting `minimum width` for the inner nodes?

*Context*

To give my question some substance, I define a command `\textnode` that transforms any text into a tikz node, allowing for easy highlighting, overlaying, etc.

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture` environments is not supported. Period. If it works, that's happenstance and you can expect it to break with a future update. If you nest them, all bets are off. You just shouldn't do this.

Comment: Consider using `tikzmark`'s `\subnode` if you need to mark nodes within nodes. Or `\tikzmark` outside `tikzpicture`s, for arbitrary text.

Comment: @cfr Well, that's sad, because apart from that little glitch, everything works really fine. I think I will accept the risk to see it break in future version, thanks for the warning.

Comment: @cfr I'll have to read `tikzmark`'s manual more thoroughly,  havn't noticed that command.

Comment: Really, there are better ways of handling this. You really don't want to nest these environments.

Comment: `\subnode` is very easy to use and was designed for exactly what you want to do :-).