# TikZ transparency group breaks with overlay

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, transparency

I was trying to implement [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227729/102121) to draw a transparent arrow using a `scope` with `transparency group`. It works fine.

Unfortunately my picture needs to be overlayed on some text. When adding the `overlay` option to my `tikzpicture` environment, the `scope`'s content simply disappears.

Is there any hope to get that working?

[image: illustration]

From left to right: no `overlay` (works), `remember picture` with `overlay` (doesn't work) on a square, `remember picture` without `overlay` (works).

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
    \fill[blue] circle (1);
    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.5]
        \fill[red] (.5,.5) circle (.5);
        \fill[red] (-.3,-.3) circle (.7);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \coordinate (z) at (0,0);
    \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[blue] (z) circle (1);
    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.5]
        \fill[red] (z) ++(.5,.5) circle (.5);
        \fill[red] (z) ++(-.3,-.3) circle (.7);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \fill[blue] (z) circle (1);
    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.5]
        \fill[red] (z) ++(.5,.5) circle (.5);
        \fill[red] (z) ++(-.3,-.3) circle (.7);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is described in the documentation: tikz has to know the size of the picture to be able to produce a correct box, but this size doesn't exist if you use overlay. Section 115.4 Transparency Groups shows a work-around. The trick is to do what you normally don't do: put a tikz picture inside a node:

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
    \fill[blue] circle (1);
    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.5]
        \fill[red] (.5,.5) circle (.5);
        \fill[red] (-.3,-.3) circle (.7);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \coordinate (z) at (0,0);
    \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[blue] (z) circle (1);
    \node[overlay] at (z)
     { \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.5]
        \fill[red] (z) ++(.5,.5) circle (.5);
        \fill[red] (z) ++(-.3,-.3) circle (.7);
       \end{scope}
       \end{tikzpicture}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \fill[blue] (z) circle (1);
    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.5]
        \fill[red] (z) ++(.5,.5) circle (.5);
        \fill[red] (z) ++(-.3,-.3) circle (.7);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll do that.Does it mean that @cfr's comment to question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/372106/102121 is no longer relevant?

Comment: it is still relevant. Nesting is not really supported, but sometimes you have to break such a rule and at long it works ...