# circuitikz doesn't draw transmission line with overlay option

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Consider the following MWE.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) to [TL] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz} [overlay]
  \draw (0,0) to [TL] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

For some reason the transmission line symbol is not drawn when using the `overlay` option.

Why is that and how can I get around it?

Comment: Confirmed. No idea why... let me check. (It doesn't happen with `R`)...

Comment: I just released 1.4.6 with the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### update:

should be fixed starting from 1.4.6, see https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/604

##### workaround

(but it breaks `fill opacity`, mind you; proper fix in the update above)

Puzzling. In the drawing of the TL legacy shape there is a transparency group (I do not remember why) that seems to confuse or badly interact with `overlay`. Removing it fixes the issue at hand, but I have to study it a bit more.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipolescaled{RF}
{}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/tline/height}}
{tline}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/tline/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/tline/width}}
{
    \pgf@circ@res@step=.2\pgf@circ@res@right % half x axis
    % \begin{pgftransparencygroup}
        \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left+\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpatharc{-90}{90}{-\pgf@circ@res@step and -\pgf@circ@res@up}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgf@circ@draworfill
        \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
        {\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgf@circ@draworfill
    % \end{pgftransparencygroup}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) to [TL] (2,0) to[R] (4,0) to[generic] (6,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz} [overlay]
  \draw (0,0) to [TL] (2,0) to[R] (4,0) to[generic] (6,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Opened an issue. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577822/tikz-transparency-group-breaks-with-overlay